# Searching different array depending on Listbox selection

Tags: arrays, vb.net

First, here is my code:

```
Public Class Form1
    'Training I
    Dim Pabumon() As String = {"Motimon", "Yokomon", "Tanemon"}

    Private Sub Training1_SelectedIndexChanged_1(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Training1.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim ArrayName As String = Training1.SelectedItem
        Dim HighSub As Integer = 0
        Training2.Items.Clear()

        For Each evo As String In ArrayName

            Training2.Items.Add(ArrayName(HighSub))
            HighSub += 1

        Next evo
    End Sub
End Class
```

My goal is to populate listbox2 from an array. I want to populate from an array with the same name as the selected item in listbox1. As of now, all it does is spell out the text of the selected index in listbox1. What I want it to do is add items Motimon, Yokomon, and Tanemon to listbox2 when I select Pabumon from listbox1.

Comment: You cant create a reference like that.  `ArrayName = Training1.SelectedItem` doesnt make `ArrayName` refer to an array.  It is just some text.  Use an If or Case statement to evaluate the selection.  Then you can add the array all at once (no loop needed): `Training2.Items.AddRange(Pabumon)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This way, as you add more items to the Training1 list, you can just add a new list to listBoxItems as shown in Form1_Load

listBoxItems will be a list of the items to add to Training2. The first item in each list is the name of the list to add to Training1

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim listBoxItems As New List(Of String())
```

Here is where you add your lists to listBoxItems and then add the first item in the lists to Training1

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        listBoxItems.Add({"Pabumon", "Motimon", "Yokomon", "Tanemon"})
        listBoxItems.Add({"List2", "cat", "dog", "pig"})
        listBoxItems.Add({"List3", "cow", "Chicken", "Horse"})
        PopulateTraining1()
    End Sub
```

This goes through each list in listBoxItems to add the first item to Training1

```
    Private Sub PopulateTraining1()
        For Each item As String() In listBoxItems
            Training1.Items.Add(item(0))
        Next
    End Sub
```

This will clear Training2, search through listBoxItems until it finds a match for listName and populate Training2 with the rest of the items found in that list.

```
    Private Sub PopulateTraining2(listName As String)
        Training2.Items.Clear()
        Dim tempList As New List(Of String)
        For Each training2List As String() In listBoxItems
            If training2List(0) = listName Then
                For listItems As Integer = 1 To training2List.Count - 1
                    Training2.Items.Add(training2List(listItems))
                Next
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

This accomplishes the same as your original code but using the new data

```
    Private Sub Training1_SelectedIndexChanged_1(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Training1.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim highSub As Integer
        PopulateTraining2(Training1.SelectedItem.ToString)
        highSub = Training2.Items.Count
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: `When You're naming variables, you should use camel case (lowercase for the first word, capital letter for the beginning of each subsequent word` I would have to say this not a must but depends on the convention and set of rules from job to job. I know our company has our own set of conventions that meet our interest; it's a controversial issue you may say...

Comment: True - each company has their own rules, but I just try to apply Microsoft's  conventions. It would make sense for everyone to use one set of guidelines I think.

Comment: I was trying to keep the code short because my Training1 listbox is going to have several more items and I want Training2 listbox to change depending on the selection. I thought something like:

Training2.Items.Add(Training1.SelectedItem(HighSub))

would work.

Comment: @DanielWatts OK I've changed the answer - there is more code, but it is dead easy to add more items.